# Error passing value in segue between ViewController and UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have been having trouble with what seems to be a fairly simple problem but I can't for the life of me work it out.

My initial view is a single view not embedded in anything where the user logs in. After they press a button I want to transition to a view that is part of a 2 tabbed `UITabBarController` that is also embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I have tried every type of Segue but I either get a `NSInvalidArgumentException` with the `UITabBarController` or it takes me to the next view but the tab bar and the navigation bar do not appear on the screen.

Hopefully this is detailed enough to understand what I am trying to do, if it is not I can upload a picture of my storyboard.

Edit - Here is my storyboard and my prepareForSegue method

Storyboard : http://oi60.tinypic.com/2pyub0o.jpg

```
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfPlayers;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tbc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPAMainViewController *mvc;


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"startGameSegue"]){
    self.numberOfPlayers = [[self.textField text] intValue];
    self.tbc = (UITabBarController *) [segue destinationViewController];
    self.mvc = [self.tbc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    self.mvc.numberOfPlayers = self.numberOfPlayers;

}
```

The error I am currently encountering is "-[UINavigationController setNumberOfPlayers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc103493380"

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't embed a tab bar controller in a navigation controller. Apple says this about using tab bar controllers and navigation controllers together, "An app that uses a tab bar controller can also use navigation controllers in one or more tabs. When combining these two types of view controller in the same user interface, the tab bar controller always acts as the wrapper for the navigation controllers." In other words, you can have navigation controllers in a tab bar controller, but not the other way around.

Comment: Sorry my wording may have been a bit confusing, the tab bar is not embedded in a navigation controller as far as I know. The view that I want to show which is also the first of the 2 tabs is embedded in a Navigation Controller and TabBarController.

Comment: If you present the tab view controller modally, you should see whatever is the root view controller of the navigation controller in the first tab. Is that what you want to see?

Comment: Yes this is what I thought would work and I think is the solution. I think I figured out where my issue. When i prepareForSegue I need to pass a textField value to the view controller of the first tab. So I was creating an instance of that view controller and then setting it as the destinationViewController, while in the storyboard I have the segue going from the button to the TabBarController which is I think where my problem is.

Comment: Yes, you don't want to be creating a new instance of that controller, you need to get a pointer to the one you have.

Comment: @NorcalAussie - the title to your question should summarize your problem. It should not be a collection of tags. You should also include the image with the question, and not put it on some site somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is my first question on here, it says I do not have enough reputation to post the image.

Comment: i'm aslo getting same problem what is the Solution @NorcalAussie how did you fix this